# Is it correct to say "there is not enough elevator in the building."?

Tags: negation

Let's suppose that there is only two elevator in my company building which is not sufficient to accommodate all the people in the building so it will take much time to go up or down to lobby. Can I say

> There is not enough elevator in the building.

and if there's grammatical error in my thread, plz let me know! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The correct way to say this would be "There aren't enough elevators in the building", "There aren't a sufficient number of elevators in the building" or "This building does not have a sufficient number of elevators".

Answer (score 1):

As Sid stated, the correct ways to say it are:

- "There aren't enough elevators in the building"
- "There aren't a sufficient number of elevators in the building"
- "This building does not have a sufficient number of elevators"

The word "elevator" isn't uncountable like say "air" or "space" for instance.

So you can't say "There isn't enough elevator". You need to use the plural form "elevators" and because of this change the "isn't" to "aren't".

Comment: Actually, you could say "There isn't enough elevator in the building".  It would be uncountable usage, but it would mean something different.  That would describe a building with one or more elevators, and they are not tall enough to go from the bottom floor to the top.  So there would be some floors impossible to reach.  "Elevator" would refer to the concept of an elevator and the fact that there isn't enough of it to do the job.  The people who build buildings are very careful not to do that because it is such a waste of good floors, which is why you never hear this version of the sentence.

Comment: @fixer1234 "good floors"...lol